# Is possible put PHP code instead of text in Title attribute in the DIV tag

Tags: php, wordpress, html, title

Is this possible? `<div id="example" title="is possible put PHP code here?"> some text </div>`
I want put `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` in the Title attribute

Comment: Try it and let us know the result.

Comment: try it...`<div id="example" title="<?php the_excerpt(); ?>">`

Comment: No, definitely not possible, dont even try that, universe might collapse...

Comment: Or the world that's predestined to come to an end in Dec'2012 will end today itself... :)

Comment: Very funny but it seems that the real problem in the WP loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
<div id="example" title="<?php echo the_excerpt(); ?>"> some text </div>
```

or:

```
<div id="example" title="<?= the_excerpt() ?>"> some text </div>
```

The latter is a shorthand that automatically echoes everything in the PHP block, whereas the former can contain any code, including code that echoes something (prints it to where the block is).

See [**basic syntax**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

Take note, however, to escape anything you output to HTML, to make sure it's a valid attribute value (unless `the_excerpt()` already returns an escaped string):

```
<div id="example" title="<?= htmlspecialchars(the_excerpt()) ?>"> some text </div>
```

Comment: Nope! it doesn't work right in a Loop!

Comment: @zainteresovansam: Be more specific. Where is the loop in relation to my example code?

Comment: <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" > <div class="postcontent"><div class="example144" title="<?php echo the_excerpt(); ?>"><?php if (is_syndicated()) : ?>  <a href="<?php the_syndication_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"  target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a>  <?php else : ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'onenews' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php endif; ?></div>

Comment: You're confusing the difference between `<?php ?>` and `<?= ?>`, I suggest you look at the linked documentation again.

Comment: Solved, the secret is a hidden API that does the job: get_the_excerpt()